# Atan2 returns the the value in a different quadrant in C#

Tags: c#

Why are the results different in C# than in MATLAB? Why am I getting the opposite side of the quadrant? Example; rather than getting 0, I am getting Pi. Is it that C# is Atan2(X,Y) by default or is it Atan2(Y,X) etc?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Testing
{
    class Inverse

    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            {
                //test Atan2 c# vs Matlab
                double a = Math.Atan2(0, 0);
                double b = Math.Atan2(0, -0);
                double c = Math.Atan2(-0, 0);
                double d = Math.Atan2(-0, -0);
                Console.WriteLine("a  = " + a);
                Console.WriteLine("b  = " + b);
                Console.WriteLine("c  = " + c);
                Console.WriteLine("d  = " + d);

                double AX = 0;
                double BY = 0;
                Console.WriteLine("aa  = " + Math.Atan2(AX, BY));
                Console.WriteLine("bb  = " + Math.Atan2(AX, -BY));
                Console.WriteLine("cc  = " + Math.Atan2(-AX, BY));
                Console.WriteLine("dd  = " + Math.Atan2(-AX, -BY));

                Console.WriteLine("aaa  = " + Math.Atan2(BY, AX));
                Console.WriteLine("bbb  = " + Math.Atan2(-BY, AX));
                Console.WriteLine("ccc  = " + Math.Atan2(BY, -AX));
                Console.WriteLine("ddd  = " + Math.Atan2(-BY, -AX));
               
            }
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
```

[Images showing results for C#](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6ySO.png)

[Images showing results for MATLAB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fv5hv.png)

Comment: `-0` in C# is an *integer* literal that produces `0` since *integers* don't support negative zero in C#. Your other examples working in the domain of *doubles* do have access to negative zero, so that's why they're different. Not sure whether matlab distinguishes between ints and doubles or has a unified number type, but I wonder if things yould be different if you used literals that are obviously not integers (e.g. `0.0` instead of `0`)

Comment: Anyhow, the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.atan2?view=net-6.0) does explain how `Math.Atan2` determines its results.

Comment: Thank you. Even if I use 0.0 etc it's the same. This was just testing to figure out a larger computation. This helps: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-sharp-math-atan2-method/